# Creating a text file filled with custom formatted text

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, combinations

I am trying to create a password list that has all the combinations in the following format:

3 characters 2 numbers 3 characters

example: `aaa00aaa` `bbb11bbb`

I have created a code that does it with smaller arrays of characters however when I try to use all characters in the ASCII system the code gives out a memory error.

```
import string

numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

characterCombs = []
numbCombs = []
allCombs = []

for el1 in characters:
    for el2 in characters:
        for el3 in characters:
            characterCombs.append(el1+el2+el3)

for n1 in numbers:
    for n2 in numbers:
        numbCombs.append(n1 + n2)

for ch1 in characterCombs:
    for no in numbCombs:
        for ch2 in characterCombs:
            allCombs.append(ch1+no+ch2)
for i in allCombs:
    f.write(i+"\n")
f.close()
```

is there a way to optimize this code or should I change my approach and find different ways to combine all these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python `itertools` module to generate combinations.

```py
from itertools import permutations

numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

for a in permutations(characters, 3):
    for b in permutations(numbers, 2):
        for c in permutations(characters, 3):
            print("".join(a + b + c))
```

This is going to take quite a lot of time though ...

---

Also, you don't need to keep a list of all the generated passwords. You can write the passwords in your file inside the for-loops as you generate them.

---

EDIT:

As @Andreas mentioned below, it should be indeed all the permutations (not combinations). I updated the code.

Comment: i think you need permutations instead of combinations, also it should be 30.891.577.600 possible combinations.

Comment: Yes indeed, I updated the answer, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know about itertools and tried to create everything by myself. This made my job way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you lack the understanding of what `for` does.
For some reason you think that it randomly picks a value, that is not what it does. `for` cycles through every element in a given iterable.
It makes sense that you get a memory error based on how huge the result of the first section is.

```
for el1 in characters:
    for el2 in characters:
        for el3 in characters:
            characterCombs.append(el1+el2+el3)
```

What happens here is this:

```
el1 = "a"
    el2 = "a"
        el3 = "a"
            characterCombs[aaa]
        el3 = "b"
            characterCombs[aaa, aab]
        el3 = "c"
            characterCombs[aaa, aab, aac]
        ...
    el2 = "b"
        el3 = "a"
            characterCombs[aaa, aab, aac, ..., aba]
```

This is easy to solve using randomizing. This is using [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
import random

def main():
    numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", 
                  "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
                  "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

pass_format = ((3, characters), (2, numbers), (3, characters))

pass_choices = tuple(random.choice(lst[1]) for lst in pass_format for _ in range(lst[0]))
print(pass_choices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It prints:
`('r', 'w', 'c', '3', '9', 'n', 'j', 'x')`

Another option, using [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
def main():
    numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", 
                  "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
                  "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

    pass_format = ((3, characters), (2, numbers), (3, characters))

    pass_choices = []
    for section in pass_format:
        pass_choices.extend(random.choices(section[1], k=section[0]))
    print(pass_choices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```